# Fuseki - server configuration

Tags: java, jetty, sparql, semantic-web, fuseki

I would like to do a benchmark in order to compare the performances among different triple stores.

In this case I am using Fuseki Server. I would like to limit the RAM and the number of threads used. I would like to run fuseki-server from command line.

I know how to limit the RAM : I can limit the max heap memory allowed by typing from prompt  -Xmx4G ( in this case I limit it to 4 GB).
I think I also know how to limit the number of threads: I just need to put in the Fuseki-server directory a xml file (in this case called jetty.xml) how it is explained here: [xml file](https://github.com/NatLibFi/Skosmos/wiki/FusekiTuning).

So from command prompt I run

`java -Xmx4G -jar fuseki-server.jar --jetty-config=jetty.xml`

and I get the following error

> [2015-10-08 08:56:22] Server     INFO  Jetty server config file = jetty.xml
>   [2015-10-08 08:56:22] XmlConfiguration WARN  Config error at name="addConnector">
>
> ```
>  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector"><Set >name="port">3030</Set><Set name="maxIdleTime">0</Set><Set >name="requestHeaderSize">65536</Set><Set >name="requestBufferSize">5242880</Set><Set >name="responseBufferSize">5242880</Set></New>
> ```
>
> [2015-10-08 08:56:22] Server     ERROR SPARQLServer: Failed to configure >server: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector
>          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.nodeClass(XmlConfiguration.java:364)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.newObj(XmlConfiguration.java:754)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.itemValue(XmlConfiguration.java:1125)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.value(XmlConfiguration.java:1030)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.call(XmlConfiguration.java:721)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:417)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:298)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.configServer(JettyFuseki.java:266)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.buildServerWebapp(JettyFuseki.java:223)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.(JettyFuseki.java:92)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.initializeServer(JettyFuseki.java:87)
>          at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:330)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:102)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:63)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:50)
>          at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:>97)
>          at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)
>   org.apache.jena.fuseki.FusekiException: Failed to configure a server using >configuration file 'jetty.xml'
>          at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.configServer(JettyFuseki.java:270)
>          at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.buildServerWebapp(JettyFuseki.java:2>23)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.>(JettyFuseki.java:92)
>          at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.jetty.JettyFuseki.initializeServer(JettyFuseki.java:8>7)
>         at >org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:330)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:102)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:63)
>          at arq.cmdline.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:50)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:97)
>           at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:60)

Do you think I miss some class in the classpath? 
And where should I add them?

Thanks in advanced.
I apologize for my poor formatting style but I am not used to ask questions, If you tell my how to improve it I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Fuseki2 which uses Jetty9.  SelectChannelConnector is for Jetty8 (as used by Fuseki1).  Jetty8 and Jetty9 are quite different in this area.  See the Jetty9 documentation.

`-Xmx4G` will likely slow Fuseki down and it does not limit the amount of RAM.  TDB uses memory mapped files and these do not contribute to heap space.  What is more, engaing the heap takes space away from the OS memory mapped file cache.